# Testing a low pass filter

Tags: c, audio, filter, signal-processing

What is a simple way to see if my low-pass filter is working? I'm in the process of designing a low-pass filter and would like to run tests on it in a relatively straight forward manner.

Presently I open up a `WAV` file and stick all the samples in a array of ints. I then run the array through the low-pass filter to create a new array. What would an easy way to check if the low-pass filter worked?

All of this is done in C.

Comment: Render a WAV-file out of the results and play it with any player. Actually, maybe you even get around rendering a WAV by simply writing the data into a RAW file, playing it back with a player that lets you manually supply details like sample-width, channel count and sample-rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two monotone signals, one of a low frequency and one of a high frequency. Then run your filter on the two. If it works, then the low frequency signal should be unmodified whereas the high frequency signal will be filtered out.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a broadband signal such as white noise to measure the frequency response:

- generate white noise input signal
- pass white noise signal through filter
- take FFT of output from filter
- compute log magnitude of FFT
- plot log magnitude

Rather than coding this all up you can just dump the output from the filter to a text file and then do the analysis in e.g. MATLAB or Octave (hint: use [periodogram](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/periodogram.html)).

Comment: This would be my choice.  Not just checking if it's working, but examining its characteristics too.

Comment: You might want to FFT the input signal as well, to see if your white noise is really white, and/or to compensate if it isn't.

Comment: @hotpaw2: Yes, you could then calculate the cross power spectrum, which would probably be smoother than the power spectrum of the output.

Comment: +1. This seems like a more comprehensive test to me. Is there any easy way to establish the phase response of the filter as well?

Comment: You can get the magnitude and phase response from the cross spectrum.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what you want to test. I'm not a DSP expert, but I know there are different things one could measure about your filter (if that's what you mean by testing).

If the filter is linear then all information of the filter can be found in the impulse response. Read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_filter

E.g. if you take the Fourier transform of the impulse response, you'll get the frequency response. The frequency response easily tells you if the low-pass filter is worth it's name.

Maybe I underestimate your knowledge about DSP, but I recommend you to read the book on this website: http://www.dspguide.com. It's a very accessible book without difficult math. It's available as a real book, but you can also read it online for free.

EDIT: After reading it I'm convinced that every programmer that ever touches an ADC should definitely have read this book first. I discovered that I did a lot of things the difficult way in past projects that I could have done a thousand times better when I had a little bit more knowledge about DSP. Most of the times an unexperienced programmer is doing DSP without knowing it.

Answer (score 1):

Like Bart above mentioned. 
If it's LTI system, I would insert impulse and record the samples and perform FFT using matlab and plot magnitude.
You ask why? 
In time domain, you have to convolute the input x(t) with the impulse response d(t) to get the transfer function which is tedious. 
y(t) = x(t) * d(t)

In frequency domain, convolution becomes simple multiplication. 
y(s) = x(s) x d(s)
So, transfer function is y(s)/x(s) = d(s). 
That's the reason you take FFT of impulse response to see the behavior of the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to programmatically generate tones (sine waves) of various frequencies, stuff them into the input array, and then compare the signal energy by summing the squared values of the arrays (and dividing by the length, though that's mathematically not necessary here because the signals should be the same length).  The ratio of the output energy to the input energy gives you the filter gain.  If your LPF is working correctly, the gain should be close to 1 for low frequencies, close to 0.5 at the bandwidth frequency, and close to zero for high frequencies.

A note:  There are various (but essentially the same in spirit) definitions of "bandwidth" and  "gain".  The method I've suggested should be relatively insensitive to the transient response of the filter because it's essentially averaging the intensity of the signal, though you could improve it by ignoring the first T samples of the input, where T is related to the filter bandwidth.  Either way, make sure that the signals are long compared to the inverse of the filter bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

When I check a digital filter, I compute the magnitude response graph for the filter and plot it. I then generate a linear sweeping sine wave in code or using Audacity, and pass the sweeping sine wave through the filter (taking into account that things might get louder, so the sine wave is quiet enough not to clip) . A visual check is usually enough to assert that the filter is doing what I think it should. If you don't know how to compute the magnitude response I suspect there are tools out there that will compute it for you.

Depending on how certain you want to be, you don't even have to do that. You can just process the linear sweep and see that it attenuated the higher frequencies.